# Ng-View is not give the output "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Ng-View is not give the output   . Trying to route form one page to another by page instead i getting this error .

> "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Kindly check the following and give your suggestion to overcome that .
App.jss

'use strict';

```
var app = angular.module('Sab', ['ui.filters','ui','ngRoute'])

.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/home', {
          templateUrl: 'index.html',
          controller: 'menuCtrl'
      }).
      when('/Deals/:offer_name', {
          templateUrl: 'Deals.html',
          controller: 'abCtrl'
      }).
      when('/D', {
            templateUrl: 'D.html',

      }).
      otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/home'
      });
}])


.controller('menuCtrl', function($scope,$http) {


     $http.get("http://tools.vcommission.com/api/coupons.php?apikey=e159f64e3dd49fddc3bb21dcda70f10c6670ea91aac30c7cb1d4ed37b20c45b8").then(function (response) {
      $scope.myData = response.data;
      $scope.offerName = ''; //set initially
      $scope.selectedIndex = -1;
      $scope.filteredOffers = [];



  });
 $scope.showData = function(offer_name, index) {
        $scope.offerName = offer_name;
      $scope.filteredOffers = $scope.myData.filter(function(offer) {
        return offer.offer_name == $scope.offerName;
      });
        $scope.selectedIndex = index;

      }


})

.controller('abCtrl',function($scope,$http,$stateParams,$filter,$window) {


$http.get("http://tools.vcommission.com/api/coupons.php?apikey=e159f64e3dd49fddc3bb21dcda70f10c6670ea91aac30c7cb1d4ed37b20c45b8").then(function (response) {


      var offerName = $stateParams.offer_name;
      $scope.filteredOffers = $filter('filter')(response.data, {offer_name: offerName});
    //  $scope.filteredOffers = _.filter(response.data, ["offer_name",offerName]);

      console.log($scope.filteredOffers)
      console.log(offerName)


      $scope.dealopen = function($a){
            for (var i=0;i<response.data.length;i++)
        {
            //console.log($scope.data[i].name);
            $link=response.data[i].link;

            if ($link==$a)
            {

            $window.open($link,"_self","location=yes"); 
            console.log($a);
            }




        }



        }
      });


});
```

Html

```
<div class="row" ng-app="Sab" ng-controller="menuCtrl" >
                  <ng-view></ng-view>

                  <div class="col col-100    " ng-repeat="da in myData | unique: 'store_image'" >
            <div class="card col " >

                   <img class="   img-responsive " ng-src="{{ da.store_image}}" 
ng-click="showData(da.offer_name, $index)"
                    />   
                <div class="caption">
                   <a class="item item-text-wrap" href="#/Deals/{{da.offer_name }}" ng-click="showData(da.offer_name, $index)"
 >
                    <b class="group inner list-group-item-heading center-block">
                        {{da.category }} Deals </b>

              </a>

                  </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>









                    </div>
```

Comment: The data you're calling is _huge_. It's a 2 MB array. This has probably to do with "Maximum call stack exceeded".

Comment: but thats works fine in ionic .. and how to overcome this

Comment: It doesn't seem like connected to large data. More looks like infinite nested routing or some other kind of infinite recursion. Can you provide us a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

First, which comes to mind - infinite recursion. First of all, your `menuCtrl` is loaded two times:

1. In html

   ```
   ng-controller="menuCtrl"
   ```
2. In route

   ```
   when('/home', {
     templateUrl: 'index.html',
     controller: 'menuCtrl'
   })
   ```

Let's start from fixing this. The next depends, I think on your other html templates.

Comment: Yes, we can. How? Skype?

Comment: me at gmail at bhatnagarabhi2411@gmail.com where on Team viewer u can check that